# How to redirect to my squid proxy using iptables since DNAT target: only valid in nat table

Tags: redirect, iptables, nat, squid

I want to redirect the traffic in my lan network through squid proxy but I am having some problems with `iptables` rules.

When I use the following rule:

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.196:3128
```

I get the following error:

```
x_tables: ip_tables: DNAT target: only valid in nat table, not filter
```

I have tried using `PREROUTING` chain but there is nothing like this in my iptables:

```
# iptables -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.196:3128
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I am using iptables version `v.1.4.10`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your WAN is on eth0 and LAN is on eth1 and that your proxy is on port 8080, what you're looking for is this:

`iptables A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080`